# Matlab Socket Server read and print input string

Tags: matlab

I am trying to setup a socket server in Matlab, so I can use other program to use Socket to write and retrieve response from Matlab. 
String data is sent through socket connection,e.g. "Hello World";

```
socket=tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server')
fopen(socket)    
data=fread(t)
```

However string is not printed, instead, integer data is showed up in the Matlab console.

```
data =

    72
   105
    32
   116
   104
  101
   114
   101
    72
   105
    32
   116
   104
   101
   114
   101
    72
   105
    32
   116
   104
   101
```

Can someone help please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the data to char:

```
char(data')

ans =

Hi thereHi thereHi the
```

Alternatively you can use the precision argument of fread, which causes char output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fscanf to read text data

```
data = fscanf(t)
```

More info: http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/writing-and-reading-data_f16-57447.html#btfksnp